# How to set UILabel non rectangular frame

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

Im trying to make a UILabel with the edges looking like the following image.

[image]

Here is the `drawRect:` from my `UILabel` subclass.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

        [super drawRect:rect];
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGRect labelRect = self.bounds;

        CGPoint bottomPoint = CGPointMake(labelRect.size.width, rect.size.height);
        CGPoint topMinus30Point =CGPointMake(labelRect.size.width-30, 0);
        CGPoint topPoint = CGPointMake(labelRect.size.width, 0);

        CGContextBeginPath (context);
        //from bottom to -30 top
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, bottomPoint.x,bottomPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, topMinus30Point.x,topMinus30Point.y);

        //from -30 to top
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, topMinus30Point.x,topMinus30Point.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, topPoint.x,topPoint.y);

        //from top to bottom
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, topPoint.x,topPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bottomPoint.x,bottomPoint.y);
        CGContextClosePath(context);

        CGContextStrokePath(context);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}
```

How do I crop the created path from the current frame ?
[Im just getting started with Core Graphics, so please be gentle :)]

Any pointers on how to achieve this would be really helpful.
Thanks

Comment: stupid thing you're looking for....you can do this in such a way set a background image with that cut right corner and above that imageview add UILable with your desired text...there is no way to achieve what you're asking

Comment: I can always do that with Images,but this is a part of my core graphics study.

Comment: you want to make the cropped part transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // clear drawing rect
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);

    // save 1
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CGRect labelRect = self.bounds;
    CGPoint bottomPoint = CGPointMake(labelRect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    CGPoint topMinus30Point = CGPointMake(labelRect.size.width-30, 0);
    CGPoint topPoint = CGPointMake(labelRect.size.width, 0);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, topMinus30Point.x, topMinus30Point.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bottomPoint.x, bottomPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0.0f, bottomPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    CGContextClosePath(context);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);

    // restore 1
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

}
```

Put this in the init you use:

```
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: Thanks joao,exactly what I wanted.

Comment: also,[super drawRect:rect];

Comment: indeed, you need that to draw the text :) Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

One approach is,

set the background color of label to clear color, and draw the required shape inside your drawRect method using CGContext.

Your drawRect will become like this

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

[super drawRect:rect];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGRect labelRect = self.bounds;


CGPoint bottomPoint = CGPointMake(labelRect.size.width, rect.size.height);
CGPoint topMinus30Point =CGPointMake(labelRect.size.width-30, 0);

//from bottom to -30 top

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x,self.bounds.origin.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, topMinus30Point.x,topMinus30Point.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bottomPoint.x,bottomPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x,self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x,self.bounds.origin.y);


CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillPath(context);

}
```

Another approach is using the `CGContextClip`  using this approach your drawRect will become like this

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x,self.bounds.origin.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, topMinus30Point.x,topMinus30Point.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bottomPoint.x,bottomPoint.y);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x,self.bounds.origin.x + self.bounds.size.height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x,self.bounds.origin.y);
CGContextClip(context);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor greenColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);
```

Hope this helps